# What are the key differences between controlled and uncontrolled airspace under the FAA jurisdiction?

Tags: faa-regulations, airspace

The FAA utilizes the ICAO definitions for class A-E airspace as controlled and class G as uncontrolled (class F airspace is unused under the FAA). What are the key differences between controlled and uncontrolled airspace in general?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This Document](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/pilot_handbook/media/PHAK%20-%20Chapter%2014.pdf) covers all the regs pretty well. But in short the key point on class G (uncontrolled) is

> Although **ATC has no authority
>   or responsibility to control air traffic**, pilots should remember
>   there are visual flight rules (VFR) minimums which apply
>   to Class G airspace.

Class G airspace also holds no specific entry requirements (aside from VFR minimums), no specific aircraft equipment (no radio, no transponder etc) and no minimum pilot certificate requirement (but you still need a license (one of a few varieties) you just don't need anything in addition like the instrument rating requirements for class A). On the contrary glass G airspace (uncontrolled) is not a free for all and you are not free to do as you please in some regards. While ATC has no reach into Class G the FAA does and you are still bound by the regulations the FAA puts forth that apply to class G airspace.

Likewise the definition they provide for controlled is

> Controlled airspace is a generic term that **covers the
>   different classifications of airspace and defined dimensions
>   within which air traffic control (ATC) service is provided**
>   in accordance with the airspace classification.

If you are wondering what the specific purpose of ATC is they define that as well,

> The primary purpose of the ATC system is to prevent a
>   collision between aircraft operating in the system and to
>   organize and expedite the flow of traffic.

Comment: You might want to rephrase your comment about "no minimum pilot certificate", it makes it sound like you can go flying in class G with no certificate at all. The document you quoted actually says "no specific requirement", which also applies to class E (and C and D).

Answer (score 2):

The shortest answer is: in uncontrolled airspace, you fly IFR without a clearance (and no clearance is available); in controlled airspace, you cannot fly IFR without a clearance.

That is the only real difference. Everything else (like weather minimums for VFR) follows from that.

BTW Class E is controlled airspace, and has no specific entry requirements for VFR either.